# Parse.com stress testing iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, parse-platform, load-testing

I'm building an app where I wish to use `Parse` as the backend platform.

I feel the app is going to be quite **request heavy** so I am doubting that I can financially sustain the app.

I would like a mechanism to be able to **test my app with a lot of users** before production, ideally with some form of `XCode` testing.

Are there any tools or techniques that are used for this kind of situation to create users and make them execute actions at semi-random intervals to test the load?

I know this is a relatively vagues question but I'm just looking for some pointers in the right direction here.

Comment: If you can model the client network activity, it might be better to leave the app out of the testing and use something scriptable on a desktop system (like curl) to do a simulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your best bet if you want to use XCode is to do a multithreaded stress test.  Three simple steps:

1. Set up a number of stressful calls (queries, saves, etc.) on separate threads.

   ```
   //First, create a Grand Central Dispatch Queue
   dispatch_queue_t specialQueue;
   specialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourcompanyname.yourappname", NULL);

   //Then run the thread a set number of times with your method you want to test
   int totalThreads = 200; //you could make this as big or small as you need to stress test
   for (int i = 0; i < totalThreads; i++) {
       dispatch_async(specialQueue, ^{ [self yourMethod]; });
   }
   ```
2. Second, run the queries in quick succession automatically (see above code to change the number of calls you make).
3. Watch your query and stress levels on the Parse.com dashboard.